# Access data from response using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using api which return me this response:-

```
{ 
 VJiQND:
  { 
   optin: 'double',
   is_default: 'no',
   from_email: 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
   name: 'ding',
   reply_to_email: 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
   created_on: '2015-05-18 11:32:37',
   from_name: 'Xa' 
 },
 VJj3KAS:
 {
 optin: 'double',
 is_default: 'yes',
 from_email: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
 name: 'xtusxx',
 reply_to_email: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
 created_on: '2015-05-18 09:09:43',
 from_name: 'Ads'
} 
}
```

now I want to get `VJj3KAS` if from_name equals to 'Ads' I try `filter` function but it didn't work it throw me an error can you please help me to get that value.

Thanks

Comment: not valid json - please use a [jsonlint](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Yes I know not valid json but this is what web api returns.

Comment: What is your code so far? If you ask why something isn't working you'll have to show the code that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function works for arrays and what you have there is a map. You must simply iterate through the map key/value pairs and check if they match your condition.

```
function getFilteredKeys(map, filter) {
  var filteredKeys = [];
  for (var key in map) {
    if (filter(key, map[key])) {
      filteredKeys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return filteredKeys;
}
```

Usage:

```
var keys = getFilteredKeys(apiResult, function(key, value){
  return value.from_name && value.from_name === 'Ads';
});
```